# How to get access to Google Calendar events of other people with same SMTP?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

How to get access of Google calendars of other people who are working in my organization under same 'smtp' without requiring their logins? I want to create a local database of all the events that they have in their calendars.

I have tried some of the Google Calendar APIs, but they require login for each api request, which I don't want. I want to get the event list without their login.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gsuite then you can create a service account with [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#perform-g-suite-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority) this will allow you to access their calendars without requiring that they login.

If this is not a gsuite domain then you will have to have them login at least once and store the refresh token for the user once that has been stored you will be able to use that to access their calendar account when ever you want.

Comment: Is there anyway I can sync all the calendars to one. And then do API calls on that one calendar.

Comment: A calendar is a calendar I dont think you can hook them to each other.  You could make one main calendar and invite all your users to that then everyone would be able to see all the data and you can just change it in once central place